# how to check if top level class

Tags: java, reflection

With an object of Class type, how to check if it's top level class / regular object class?

Context: I'm converting object metadata to json structure and currently my code looks like

```
JsonElement toJson(Type type) {
  if (type == String.class) {
    ...
  } else if (...) { //more primitives
    ...
  } else if (type instanceof ParametrizedType) {
    ...
  } else if (type instanceof Class) {
    Class clazz = (Class) type;
    if (clazz.isEnum()) {
    ....
    }
    // probably it's an object
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you need any of that to convert to json?

Comment: Long story ;) I need to dynamically call soap webservices. And this is part of the rest service that provides metadata info about soap request and response data for the purpose of mapping editor

Comment: It’s top level when it’s neither [`isLocalClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isLocalClass()) nor [`isMemberClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isMemberClass()). But how many special cases do you want to handle? Of course, `isPrimitive()`, `isArray()`, `isEnum()`, `isInterface()`. If it’s neither of them, it’s an ordinary class (a `record` is mostly ordinary in that regard). Unless it’s *synthetic* or *hidden*.

Comment: This use of "top level class" sounds weird, what actually you need? how do you define "regular object class"? What about `ListOfCars extends List<Car>`?

Comment: The term "top level class" I've stolen - there's such private method defined in the Class. Actually I've long series if () else if () else if () else {// probably a bussiness object, iterate fields and call toJson()} and want to have if () else if () else if (isObject()) else throw new ForgotToSupportTypeException(); It's about to protect agains stack overflow - just in case as I think I've covered all of the types

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the method [`getSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) and check if the result is null or not:

> Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class. **If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned**. If this object represents an array class then the Class object representing the Object class is returned.

By the way **don't reinvent the wheel**... if you need to convert metadata to json **use a json converter library**.
Using faster jackson for example you can do:

```
// Here object is any object and json string equivalent of this object
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: I'd say it won't work, I don't want to convert an instance of an object but object's metadata. And even for the instance - let's say I'll create a dummy one for the root object - it won't work if property value is null but actually it's a complex object type with nested properites of object types etc and I need these data